# Textures Distorted on Destiny 2 with Windows 10 and bootcamp

Tags: destiny-2, boot-camp

I am playing Destiny 2 on Windows 10 bootcamped on my Mac.

When launching the game, this happened; the textures are all distorted on this screen and throughout the game. This also happens on Steam games like PUBG.

[image: Destiny 2]

Comment: Do you also have the same issue in 3D games on Mac OS? If so, it could be a problem with your hardware, otherwise it's possibly a driver issue.

Comment: Sounds like a driver issue to me as well.

Comment: What Mac do you have?